# javascript : validate price with some constraints

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html-framework-7

So, I want to validate price that user enters in my text field:

```
<input type="number" name="AdsCharges" placeholder="0.00" id="charges">
```

**Conditions(or constraints):**

1. Value should always always be greater than zero
2. Value cannot contain minus "-"
3. Value cannot contain decimal points more than once. Also value
   should not start with decimal point

Also, I have to keep in mind that this should be working on mobile too, as the app is going to be Phonegap based.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I tried this code, from [here](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/05/enter-only-numbers-using-jquery.htm). But what happens is that, on web browsers (desktop), they work perfectly, I mean, dots are not allowed more than once. But, when I use it in my phonegap app, it is allowing multiple dots.

Comment: If you are trying to use this in phonegap's webview then i would recommend you to use javascript instead for validation as the webview is not as advanced as the desktop browser is.

Comment: You can use a simple regular expression like: `/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/`, for example, you might have: `if(/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(value)) { /* ok */} else { /* not */}`.

Comment: @RobG Ok sir. I am on it.

Comment: @RobG Sir, your comment helped me. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<input type= "number" name= "five_steps" max= "30" min= "0" step= "5" value= "10" />
```

Comment: The UI framework which I am using wont fire HTML5 validations. I am using `Framework7` for building UI, unfortunately  :(

Comment: Why the minimum and maximum? Why step of 5?

Comment: @RobG  step 5 is increase counter 5 if you one increase 1 you can set setp="1" , max and min is range to enter in text.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati—I'm not asking what they do, but **why** they are there.